# How to Set the link for "Home" button for CHM file?

Tags: chm

I create a CHM help document with HTML Workshop. However, when click the "Home" button in the navigator bar, I will see this:

[image]

Our homepage will be distorted completely.

I try to find a way to set the "Home" button link but cannot a way. Finally I open .hhp file and edit the following line:

```
[WINDOWS]
main="DataNumen Outlook Repair","DOLKR.hhc","DOLKR.hhk","introduction.htm","https://www.datanumen.com/",,,,,0x62520,,0x3046,[0,0,780,660],,,,,,,0
```

But after that, when I click the "Home" page, I will get the following error:

[image]

So how to solve the problem?

The chm file(version 1) can be downloaded from https://www.datanumen.com/temp/20210113/DOLKR.chm

Answer (score 1):

The short story - AFAIK it's not possible linking to a domain or an exact location from the CHM's home button by full path URL.

CHM files offer the preferred option of the "Default Topic file" (e.g. "introduction.htm"). The "Home" button can also be suppressed by special settings, but is useful for returning to "Home" if you have previously navigated different topics. In the sense of a homepage of the HTML help file "web" this can be a "home.htm" or even the "introduction.htm".

My suggestion as a simple workaround is to create a nice home.htm and link from there to your own company page in a new browser window.

```
[WINDOWS]
main="DataNumen Outlook Repair","DOLKR.hhc","DOLKR.hhk","introduction.htm","home.htm",,,,,0x62520,0,0x3046,[0,0,780,660],0xB0000,,,,,0,
```

As mentioned by others CHM files were developed over 20 years ago and are usually only used as a local help file. The system requires Internet Explorer. You can't access complex web pages because of the **outdated Internet Explorer** browser.

It is possible to link to simple HTML pages on the internet via the table of contents file (.hhc) as shown below. Please keep in mind that a customer using a local CHM help file requires an internet connection.

```
<!DOCTYPE HTML PUBLIC "-//IETF//DTD HTML//EN">
<HTML>
<HEAD>
<meta name="GENERATOR" content="Microsoft&reg; HTML Help Workshop 4.1">
<!-- Sitemap 1.0 -->
</HEAD><BODY>
<UL>
    <LI><OBJECT type="text/sitemap">
          <param name="Name" value="Jump directly from here (help-info.de)">
          <param name="Local" value="https://www.help-info.de/index.htm">
          <param name="ImageNumber" value="13">
        </OBJECT>
    <LI> <OBJECT type="text/sitemap">
        <param name="Name" value="Introduction">
        <param name="Local" value="introduction.htm">
        </OBJECT>
    <LI> <OBJECT type="text/sitemap">
        <param name="Name" value="System requirements">
        <param name="Local" value="requirements.htm">
        </OBJECT>
    <LI> <OBJECT type="text/sitemap">
        <param name="Name" value="Usages">
        </OBJECT>
    <UL>
        <LI> <OBJECT type="text/sitemap">
            <param name="Name" value="Repair file">
            <param name="Local" value="repairfile.htm">
            </OBJECT>
...
```

[image]

Answer (score 0):

The Microsoft HTML help viewer used to display CHM help files is very old and not maintained by Microsoft anymore: it is using an older version of Internet Explorer to display topic content and external URLs which might break modern web-sites, and I suspect that this is the cause of your problem.

Some possible solutions include:

- You can create a specific page for your web-site which work on older versions of Internet Explorer and link to that page instead
- You can create a [link to a _blank target](https://www.w3schools.com/tags/att_a_target.asp) which will open that page in your standard web-browser instead of the Microsoft HTML help viewer